# Apache2 can't access any Content

Tags: apache, apache2

I'm using Apache2 for a local Piwik server for testing and this morning it suddenly stopped working. When I try to access `http://127.0.1.1/piwik/index.php` all I get is a 404 stating it couldn't find the requested URL. In fact I can't even produce the standard index.html, only the "It Worked" default page.

My files are all in `var/www/html` and this is what my 000-default.conf looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   #ServerName www.example.com

   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

As you can see, I haven't changed a thing and until this morning the Piwik server worked perfectly.

Any help would be appreciated but please note that I am new to Linux and Apache so please take this into consideration when answering.

Comment: Can you show the output of `apache2ctl -S`? Also have you tried to restart the apache service `sudo service apache2 restart`. Can you also show the contents of any `.htaccess` file located under the `/var/www/html` folder?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a issue with `.htaccess` or possibly a missing `Allowoverride` directive for the `/var/www/html` folder.

Comment: @Cyclonecode [This is my Output to apache2ctl -S](http://imgur.com/RgZ7DEb)

I actually completely reinstalled Apache today and I don't seem to have any `.htaccess` files in my folder.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

maybe you are missing Directory part to access files